# How to make a loop over the children and open the "href" for further parsing?

Tags: python, html, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to do a parser from a local real estate web-site using python and selenium. I arrived to select the needed page and I want to go trough each element that is located in a parent directory and open each page for further parsing.

I wrote a piece of code that select the needed page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://makler.md/md/"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rublist_lev1"]/li[1]/a').click() # acces Imobiliare
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Vânzare apartamente, camere").click() # acces Apartamente
```

The HTML is:

[image]

I need the loop to iterate over the parent directory:

```html
<div class="ls-short ">
```

select every children that have an ID like:

```html
<article class="" id="tr_an-265955">
```

and click the page that is linked to it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need something like below:

```
links = []
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//article[starts-with(@id, "tr_an-")]//a[@class="ls-detail_anUrl"]'):
    links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # do whatever you need to do on that page...
```

This should gather all required page links in a list and then you can handle each page in a loop